# How to make python command to run 2.7 version and python3 run 3.8.5 version

Tags: python, python-3.x, command

I am working on Windows 10.
In the command prompt of I run Python command it should call Python 2.7. And Python3 command run 3.8 version.

Unfortunately, both the version EXEs are named as Python.exe in Windows.
I tried using Symlink to create the version file for 3.8 version.. However when I check "which python" in Git Bash console in windows, it returns both the 2.7 and 3.8 EXEs along with the Symlink.

Could you please help me on how I can get to trigger Python2.7 to be run when "Python" command is run. And to trigger Python3.8 to be run when "Python3" command is run.

PS: I tried renaming the python executable to python3.exe. But this resulted in a non-working PIP

Comment: "But this resulted in a non-working PIP"  it is a better practice anyway to use `python -m pip` and `python3 -m pip`, especially if you have multiple versions of Python

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will there be any side affects apart from non-working pip command if I rename the file? and is there any other way I could achieve the requirement?